# How to convert API data into local language data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, redux, flux

I am working on a reactJS+Flux Project.I am trying to convert my website into multi-language. I already have my dictionary of all the possible value coming from my API. I want to replace actual value of API with my dictionary value.

for example:

from API I am getting following format data:

```
data = {
 basic: {
  name: "ajay kumar",
  country: "India",
  State: "Maharashtra",
  City: "Mumbai"
 }
}
```

in my hindi dictionary I already got all value like:

```
data= {
hindi: {
"country" : {
     "India" : "भारत"
 },
state: {
        "Andaman & Nicobar Islands": "अंदमान अँड निकोबार आयलँड्स",
        "Andhra Pradesh": "आंध्र प्रदेश",
        "Arunachal Pradesh": "अरुणाचल प्रदेश",
        "Assam": "आसाम",
        "Bihar": "बिहार",
        "Maharashtra": "महाराष्ट्र"
},
"city" :{
   "Mumbai" : "मुंबई"
}
}
}
```

I want to change all of my value from given dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that your dictionary can not be a simple:

```
{englishWord1: hindiWord1,
 ....
 englishWordn: hindiWordn}
```

If it can not, I would extract the keys from `data.basic` with `Object.keys(object)` then I would define I function that map the word in your dictionary with the ones in your object (`translate(section, word, dictionary) => [section, translatedWord]`).
With `Object.keys(object)` you obtain an array of keys that correspond to the sections in you dictionary (`Country`,`State` ecc) then with `map` you transform each element in the array for di that you use `translate(..)` and you obtain an array of translated word: `[[section1:translatedWord1],...[sectionn,translatedWordn]]`. Then with a function that take array and return an object (`arrayToObject([])=>{}`) you'll have your translated object.

```js
//This is your dictionary
engToHindi = {
  Country : {
    India: 'valueIndia',
  },
  State: {
    Maharashtra: 'valueMaharashtra',
  },
  City :{
   Mumbai: 'valueMumbai',
  }
}

data = {
 basic: {
  Name: "ajay kumar",
  Country: "India",
  State: "Maharashtra",
  City: "Mumbai"
 }
}

function arrayToObject(array){
  object = {}
  array.map(x => {object[x[0]] = x[1]});
  return object;
}


function translate(section, word, dictionary){
  // If the section doesn't exist do not transalate
  if (dictionary[section] === undefined){
    return [section, word];
  }
  translatedWord = dictionary[section][word];
  return [section, translatedWord];
}

arrayToTransform = Object.keys(data.basic).map(key => translate(key, data.basic[key], engToHindi))
console.log(arrayToTransform)

transformed = arrayToObject(arrayToTransform);
console.log(transformed);
```

Please make sure that you need the dictionary divided in sections.